# Django nested formsets

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an edit object view that contains a formset(one or many if this matters), now I want to create a page that can display multiple edit object forms and submit it in a single form.

What is the correct way to achieve this task?

Comment: http://yergler.net/blog/2009/09/27/nested-formsets-with-django/

Comment: Thank you, I read this post, but it seems that it is not my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution.

I can enumerate my objects on edit page and use different prefixes for formsets based on these indexes. Here is an example:

First, you need enumeration, I achieved it using same input(checkbox) name with incremental values:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="counter" value="0">
...
<input type="checkbox" name="counter" value="1">
...
```

Counter numbers is the formset and other data serial numbers:

```
<!--Ordinary inputs-->
<input type="text" name="data0" value="value0">
<input type="text" name="data1" value="value1">
<!--Formsets-->
<input type="text" id="test0-0-data" name="test0-0-data" value="something">
<input type="text" id="test0-1-data" name="test0-1-data" value="something">
<input type="hidden" name="test0-TOTAL_FORMS" id="id_test0-TOTAL_FORMS" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="test0-INITIAL_FORMS" id="id_test0-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0">

<input type="text" id="test1-0-data" name="test1-0-data" value="something">
<input type="hidden" name="test1-TOTAL_FORMS" id="id_test1-TOTAL_FORMS" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="test1-INITIAL_FORMS" id="id_test1-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0">
```

Then if code you populate formsets like this:

```
counter = request.POST.getlist('counter')
for i in counter:
    TestFormset = modelformset_factory(Test, form=TestForm)
    test_formset = TestFormset(request.POST, prefix='test'+i, queryset=Test.objects.none())
```

I achieved HTML structure above with JavaScript.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more for a django newbie?